# H2 Database doesn’t support schema.package.function structure

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, h2, in-memory-database

In my project we are using oracle database as the main application db and H2 as in memory database to run only the integration test cases. Oracle db has many functions which are of the structure "schema.package.function()". The problem is, i'm not able to recreate the same function in H2 for integration test cases as H2 treats it in the form of "dbname.schemaname.functionname()".

for example : When code runs with oracle db , "SELECT MDM.NEXT_KEYS.NEXT_REF_SOURCE_KEY from dual" works. During integration test case on H2, it throws error "DB MDM not found". So i set the db name as MDM and schema name as NEXT_KEYS in h2 setup.It worked. But my next function PAYERS.KEY_TRANSLATIONS.CORE_ENHANCED_DESC_4_KEY fails now saying "DB PAYERS not found".

Changing the oracle functions is out of the equation as they are used by multiple teams.

If this is not possible with H2 , can you suggest a good alternate in-memory db for spring boot

Appreciate your help !

Comment: An in-memory db will never be up to the standards that full RDBMS support. You are using Oracle, then use oracle in your tests. Use something like testcontainers to bootstrap an oracle database for use in your tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue. Adding the solution link here so that it might help someone

Setting this flag IGNORE_CATALOGS=TRUE fixed the issue. When it is enabled, name of catalog (database) is ignored.

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=Oracle;IGNORE_CATALOGS=TRUE

Refer the below link https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/2893